# Symfony2 setting up (my own) secure Variables

Tags: symfony

Where is the best place to put sensible data in Symfony2, i.e. PayPal Variables (API Username, Password etc.)?

Since **app/config/** is not accessible from outside, I think this might actually be the best location. Am I correct?
If above is correct, can I add an additional **paypalconfig.yml** file to the **app/config/** folder or is it recommend to add those things to **app/config/parameters.ini**?

How can I access that data later?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, app/config is safe as long as server is setup correctly.

You could create paypalconfig.yml, but it's recommended to store in /app/config/parameters.ini

You can access it later on as DIC parameter, for example in controller: `$this->container->getParameter("my_private_paypal_param");`

Comment: I'd argue that using a separate paypalconfig.yml would be cleaner than storing the data in parameters.ini. Especially for larger applications where parameters.ini could quickly become cluttered.

Comment: @Arms each 'paypalconfig.yml' type of file is a headache if you're using any type of VCS. Also I can't imagine how big an app has to be for parameters.ini to be cluttered enough to justify separate config file. Biggest I've seen was 25-30 lines..

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I do it. I have the `parameters.yml.dist` (or `*.ini.dist`) file with dummy data in `app/config` and it's checked into the git repo. When deploying an app, I copy it to `parameters.yml` — which I configured to be ignored by git — and fill with the real data.

If you go with the same approach, your secure data will be in `parameters.yml` only and thus won't be kept in the repo.